Printed pages are flipped
I'm using Windows 11, Microsoft 365.
I have HP laserjet MFP M227fdn, using preprinted papers with headers for my business (only on the front, the back is blank).
According to the printer, I put the papers with the correct orientation in the paper feeder. When I print one page, it prints correctly on the proper side of the paper, and the appropriate orientation.
The issue is when I print more than one page. For example, when I print 2 pages, it prints the first page on the back, and the second on the front. They are both flipped (upside down).
Options in Word, print in reverse is unchecked. Flip on the long edge (I don't think this is an issue since both pages are flipped).
Help is much appreciated

Delete/uninstall printer drivers, disconnect printer, download the latest available printer drivers, install. Have you done that yet?

None of that yet, I spent the time looking in the settings and printing options.

Is this a business environment and business-owned devices?

It's my office, my device.

Then you should remove and update the drivers. Once you've done that, report back. BUT, do not add that info down here: add it instead to the question body, using the EDIT button. This will make your question more complete and so others will know what you've tried so far without having to dredge through the comments down here.

"Flip on the long edge" is a duplex printing option. Duplex printing means "double-sided," so you have duplex printing enabled, possibly by default.
Typically to change the printer defaults, you go to the "devices and printers" system settings, select the printer, select "see what's printing" and then "properties." What you set there should then be default when you open the print dialog in any software.
A quick model search suggests you are looking for "Copies & Pages" > layout > select Layout > option for double sided
